# Determining the starting value for primality test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

This question is about Lucasian primality test for numbers of the form $N=3\cdot 2^n-1$ .

There is a following statement in  Wikipedia article : [Lucas-Lehmer-Riesel test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer%E2%80%93Riesel_test#Finding_the_starting_value) :

"If $k = 3$ : if $n = 0$ or $3$ mod $4$, then $u_0 = 5778$."

However it seems that values $u_0 = 18$ and $u_0 = 488$ also fit .

[Here](http://maxima-online.org/?inc=r1342010838) is Maxima implementation of the test with starting value $u_0 = 18$ and [here](https://oeis.org/A002235) you can find a list of exponents for which $3\cdot 2^n-1$ is prime .

So , my question is : Is there any special reason why $5778$ has been chosen to be starting value instead of $18$ or $488$ ?

Comment: Maybe "it seems" is not good enough?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Maybe you are right but on the other hand I couldn't find any counterexample .

Answer (score 1):

(The case concerning the sequence starting with 18-some progress).

In the original paper Lehmer proved that
$V_{3\cdot 2^{n+1}}\equiv \ 0 \mod N \ ({\text{with}}\ N=3\cdot 2^n-1),$ where
$V_n=(\sqrt{5}-2)^n+(\sqrt{5}+2)^n\ ({\text{set}}\ a=\sqrt{5}-2,\ b=\sqrt{5}+2).$ Now note that
the sequence $\{u_n\}=\{V_{3\cdot 2^{n+1}}\}.$
For $n=0$ we get $V_6=5778$ which is set as $u_0$ (so this is the reason that 5778 was used).
The sequence which starts with $18$ is eventually the sequence
$\{V_{2^{n+1}}\}_{n\geq 1}=\{18,322,...\}.$
Using the relation $V_{3\cdot 2^{n+1}}=V_{2^{n+1}}(V_{2^{n+1}}-1)$ (from the property giving $V_{n+m}=...$)
we get $V_{2^{n+1}}(V_{2^{n+1}}-1)\equiv 0\mod N.$
Now it is enough to prove that $\gcd(V_{2^{n+1}}-1,3\cdot 2^{n}-1)=1.$